# How can I make a print and preview before printing in blazor WASM?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am new in blazor and I have a WASM project, I want to make a print, preview before printing and export for my pages how to make this

Comment: You are much more likely to get an answer on SO if you show the code you have tried and detail the errors or issues you are encountering. This is not the proper forum for simply asking, "How do I do X?" [ask]